# Why is GitLab runner job failing with more than one gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I'm attempting to run a `build` and `test` stage in my .gitlab-ci.yml file.  As of right now, I have an incredibly simple setup, but this is my first time using gradle.

Originally I had the following file:

**Non-working .gitlab-ci.yml**

```
job:
    script:
        - gradle build
```

This failed for reasons that I don't understand, but I'm assuming permission issues reaching the `.gradle` directory.

The fix was:

**Working .gitlab-ci.yml**

```
job:
    script:
        - gradle build - gradle build -g gradle-user-home
```

Adding the `-g` flag resolved the issue, and the build was successful.  However, when I attempt to run another stage, such as `test`, I get failures.

**Non-working .gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

gradle-build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - gradle build -g gradle-user-home

gradle-test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - gradle test -g gradle-user-home
```

If I remove either stage, the other stage works fine when alone.  The first one will run just fine, and the second one doesn't even show the script it tried to run, I just get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.4.1 (05161b14)
  on my-runner abcdefg
Using Shell executor...
Running on my-runner...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/abcdefg/0/user-name/project/.git/
from http://gitlab/user-name/project
    70077bc..4xyz master -> origin/master
Checking out 4dbf9934 as master...
warning: failed to remove gradle-user-home/daemon/5.6.2: Directory not empty
warning: failed to remove gradle-user-home/caches/journal-1: Directory not empty
etc... (6 more lines of this)
Removing .gradle/
Removing gradle-user-home/daemon/5.6.2/daemon-19142.out.log
etc... (20 more lines of this)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Like I said, it's confusing because if I run these separate they each work, but if I have them both in the file at the same time, this happens, and the other job skips.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the permissions of the `gitlab-runner` user on the runner, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.  It seems like the `gitlab-runner` user would be the one creating the `gradle-user-home` that it can't remove, so I'm not sure why that would be the case.  I've checked, and as expected, the `gitlab-runner` user does own everything inside of the `builds` directory.

Answer (score 0):

After a build, I clean my gradle build cache using. This makes sure the directory is clean, removing caches which may remain otherwise.

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```